# Gauss lemma for nonsmooth metric

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$g_{ij}(x)\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n, M^{n\times n})$ is a metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $\lambda |x|^2\leq g_{ij}x^ix^j\leq \Lambda |x|^2$($\lambda>0$&$\Lambda>0$)

Can we find a Lipschitz homorphism $x=f(y)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(0)=0$, s.t. the new metric 
$h_{kl}(y)=g_{ij}(f(y))\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial y^k}\frac{\partial f^j}{\partial y^l}$ satisfying Gauss lemma, That is：
$$h_{kl}(y)y^k=y^l$$

Comment: The answer is no. In dimension 2, you can find a homeomorphism, but in general it is not Lipschitz; it is quasiconformal. But in dimension $>2$ you cannot find any such homeomorphism (the system of PDE which it has to satisfy is overdetermined).

Comment: I think you are talking about uniformization theorem, did it?